# How to disable Logcat background noise

Tags: android, eclipse, apache, logcat, android-logcat

I would like to disable certain things from showing up in my logcat. They are just informatives, nothing severe. I just hate having to skim through alot of "noise" to find what I am looking for. Here are the main ones I would like not show up.

```
 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=4279) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(4614): (thUse=4279) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()
 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=4279) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(4614): (thUse=4279)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null
 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=4279) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(4614): (thUse=4279)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.
 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=4279) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(4614): (thUse=4279) isCurrentProcessRequestedGba()#finished   result=false
 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=4279) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(4614): (thUse=4279) isCurrentProcessAllowedToUseGba()#started   result=false
 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=4279) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(4614): (thUse=4279)    The GBA permission wasn't requested for this process.
 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=4279) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(4614): (thUse=4279) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=4279) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(4614): (thUse=4279)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
```

I have tried to set Loggers to just warnings, even severe. For example...

```
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("httpclient.wire.header").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.HttpEntity").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.HttpResponse").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.client.HttpClient").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.params.HttpParams").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
 Logger.getLogger("httpclient").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

But it still keeps showing up. I have also tried looking through my dependencies and going through each .jar file trying to locate these classes but it was seriously like finding a needle in a haystack.

Is there any way I can permanently disable these? I know about filtering but thats not what I am looking for.

Comment: Does this 'noise' is generated by your app or some app from the system  itself?

Comment: Its generated from my app. It's just information about my http request. I'm using Apache http to handle all json requests.

Comment: Is anyone able to shed some light?